# How to set the color of div element above inner repeater?

Tags: asp.net

I have repeater inside another repeater as the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="GroupList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="groupSeparator">
            <span class="menu"><%# Eval("GroupName") %> <%# Eval("GroupExtra") %></span>
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ActionList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a class="actionExtraData" href="Actions.aspx?ActionTypeID=<%# Eval("ActionTypeID") %>"><%# Eval("ActionType") %></a>
```

How to set the color of div element - groupSeparator, above inner repeater depending on value of ActionTypeID, which is placed inside inner repeater?

We don't need to use code behind.

Comment: The inner repeater typycally contains multiple items but you only have one `groupSeparator`-div, so what is the rule, which item do you want to use of the inner repeater, what determines the color? Also, either use a `Panel`(which is rendered as a `div`) or make it `runat=server` if you want to access the div on serverside.

Comment: You're right, that is the inner repeater contains some repeating items that are separated by div separator. I need to change the color of separator depending on value of field inside inner repeater. But, I don't need to use code behind.

Comment: You still haven't mentioned the rules. What determines the color of the div, which item in the inner repeater is relevant? _"I need to change the color of separator depending on value of field inside inner repeater."_ My point is that you have multiple items in the inner repeater but only one outer-div.

Comment: I already wrote the rule: "depending on value of ActionTypeID". For example, if the value of ActionTypeID is 20, the color of div is red.

Comment: We get the ActionTypeID from database with another fields and bind the inner repeater to that set of rows.

Comment: But you have possibly multiple `ActionTypeIDs`, what if it is 20, 10 and 5?